# add a section with specific name to my index

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to add a section with specific name, something like this:

```
@string test="test";
@section @test
{
   @*  my view code *@
}
```

How could I get this work.

Comment: where are you trying to add the section? and what are you trying to do with that section - is it a partialview or a view?

Comment: I try to add my section in places that are indicated from my database and in that section I should add that section's content. it's a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DefineSection` method. Have a look here at examples of how this can be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/15/razor-nested-layouts-and-redefined-sections.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a partial which could be included using the `Html.Partial` helper at any place:

```
@Html.Partial("test")
```

which would render the `Test.cshtml` partial view which could contain any markup you like.

If you want to handle some more complex scenarios where this partial will contain dynamic data coming from some data store you could use the [Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) helper. You would start by defining a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class MySectionController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyModel model = ...
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and have a corresponding view:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyModel
<div>@Model.SomeProperty</div>
```

and finally you would include it like this:

```
@Html.Action("index", "mysection")
```

You could include it in your layout thus allowing you to include dynamic widgets completely decoupled from your main controller logic and each of them following their natural workflow.